# ¿Cómo agregar hojas de estilo externas a mi archivo CSS?

Tags: css

Quiero añadir hojas de estilo a mi CSS, pero no puedo.
He probado dirigiéndome a la web donde están :

```
@import url(“https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One”);
@import url(“fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed”);
```

Sin resultado, por lo que me descargue esas mismas APIs en mi archivo CSS, poniéndoles un nombre cualquiera. He intento acceder a ellas de varias formas,
revisando documentación de MDN y de w3schools, sin éxito.

Alguien puede decirme la forma correcta para conseguir añadir esos estilos.
Gracias.

Comment: Después de importarlas ¿has hecho la declaración @font-face?

Comment: No, como he de hacerlo...?

Comment: Tambien tengo que decir que la estoy poniendo en una aplicacion, por eso las descargue en un archivo, las tengo en mi carpeta CSS.                                   No se si es que para lo que quiero no vale, pues se supone que no estoy conectado, de ahi que las tenga em archivos.                                                          Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```css
/* Importamos fuentes, ¡importante! que este al principio de tu CSS tu @import. */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed');

/* Creamos nuestras fuentes */

.poiret {
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.ubuntu {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="poiret">Soy la fuente Poiret One</p>
  <p class="ubuntu">Soy la fuente Ubuntu Condensed</p>
```

Una alternativa seria usar [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) y descargar la fuente como .ttf y lo conviertes en una fuente valido para tu web, sería necesario 3 formatos (`woff`, `eot`, `ttf`).

[Descargar Poiret .ttf](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=Poiret&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y) 
[Descargar Ubuntu .ttf](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=Ubuntu&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y)

Una vez descargado las fuentes los conviertes en un formato valido mediante un generador que puedes encontrar en la misma página. Seleccionas modo **EXPERT** para así seleccionar los 3 formatos necesarios (`TrueType`, `WOFF`, `EOT Lite`).

[WebFont generador](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Las fuentes que has convertidos los debes incluir a tu carpeta `raiz` de tu proyecto web, personalmente crearía una carpeta llamado `fonts` para tenerlo organizado.

**Carpeta raiz**

*fonts*

- poiretone-regular-webfont.eot
- poiretone-regular-webfont.woff
- poiretone-regular-webfont.ttf

Tu archivo `CSS` quedara algo así para añadir nuestra fuente:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poiret_oneregular';
    src: url('fonts/poiretone-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/poiretone-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),             
         url('fonts/poiretone-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/poiretone-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

/* Si deseas usar la fuente */
body {
  font-family: 'poiret_oneregular';
}
```

Comment: Hola, asi ya lo tengo, pero no me las reconoce.   No se porque , pero n funciona

Comment: @MiguelEspeso que raro, ¿has mirado que tus  `@import url` estén al principio de tu `CSS`? Digamos es lo primero que debería ir. Te he dejado también un ejemplo alternativo usando `Font Squirrel `.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a practicarlo, el problema, era que no entendia lo de format('.......................'). Creo que ahora lo pille. gracias de nuevo

Comment: De nada @MiguelEspeso, una vez generas las fuentes y lo descargas, tu archivo `winrar` también te ofrece un ejemplo `CSS`, si te ha valido la respuesta después de tus pruebas podrías aceptarla como solución, así podrá servir a otros usuarios con el mismo problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Probe lo que me digiste.Funciona, me a costado un poco, de echo no se como lo he conseguido, pues el sitio esta lleno de recursos                                                                               Al final puse los archivos en carpetas dentro de carpeta css, y funciono                                                                      Lo que no se es como "aceptar como solucion", me refiero que no se que tengo que marcar.                                                                                              Gracias por el apoyo..

Comment: @Miguel el ✔️ a la izquierda de esta respuesta, debajo de las flechas para votar... Ambos ganan reputación

Comment: Ya lo piye, gracias